# Format null number as empty space

Tags: groovy

I have a legacy app I am rewriting in groovy that converts null numbers into empty spaces.

What I did is this:

```
String.format("%25.2f",res.VOLUME_AVG_5D ?: 0.0)
```

which renders nulls as 0.0 but I need to make an empty string instead. Is there an easy groovy way to do that?

I have this formatting in a property file that evaluates dynamically, so it's not easy to do IFs there, I would prefer a one-liner if possible. 
The way it's defined is like this:

```
file.rows="${->res.COMP_KEY}|${->String.format("%25.2f",res.VOLUME_AVG_5D ?: 0.0).trim()}|${->String.format("%25.2f",res.VOLUME_AVG_10D ?: 0.0).trim()}
```

where res is resultset I get from a query also defined in property file.

Comment: How would you deal with the format string if the value passed is empty string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not switch it around, and instead of:

```
String.format("%25.2f",res.VOLUME_AVG_5D ?: 0.0)
```

Do

```
res.VOLUME_AVG_5D == null ? '' : String.format("%25.2f",res.VOLUME_AVG_5D)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Somehow I got stuck and didn't think of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<strike>String.format("%25.2f",res.VOLUME_AVG_5D ?: "@@NULL@@").replaceAll("@@NULL@@","");</strike>

Check tim's answer, this one will give `IllegalFormatConversionException` as the `%25.2f` is expecting a `float`

Comment: Won't that just give you a `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String`?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it.